# Inject doctrine in a formbuilder class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am tryin to inject the entity manager in a formbuilder class.
But i get this error :

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Pdb\Backend\Admin\RelationManagementBundle\Form\Search\SearchForm::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given.

```
services:
    my_service:
        class:      Pdb\Backend\Admin\RelationManagementBundle\Form\Search\SearchForm
        arguments:  
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

my constructor :

```
class SearchForm extends AbstractType {

protected $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are doing:  $searchForm = new SearchForm();  If so then that won't work.  Need to use the service container and you will probably need to tag it as a form service.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Comment: do you get this error at a specific point in your application or in general?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I think i need to tag it as a form service but i don't fully understand how to do this. Maybe somebody got some examples ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in controller

```
public function showAction($id,$tab)
    {
...
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $form    = $this->createForm(new Pdb\Backend\Admin\RelationManagementBundle\Form\Search\SearchForm($em), $entity);


..
}
```

then in form

```
class SearchForm extends AbstractType {

protected $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```